# How to get those help borders in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

Not sure how I should call this but I'm following a tutorial and in there he has this green help lines that indicate your selected object is at the same heigth over the overlapping object behind it, it used to be enabled but somehow it stopped showing after a while.

How do I enable this green help lines?

Here's a picture showing the green help lines: sorry for the bad quality

[image]

Answer (score 5):

They are called **Smart Guides** - ([Read more](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rulers-grids-guides-crop-marks.html#smart_guides))

They can be toggled *on/off* by hitting <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or by choosing *View → Smart Guides*.

Comment: aha okay, thought so but I wasn't sure because the object started snapping so weird and out of place I couldn't get them on the same height with smart guides enabled. Thanks tho!